# gspread - How do I enter row values using valueInputOption?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I want to have a list of changes that I can append to textRequests. Im not sure what is wrong with my syntax. I keep getting the following error:

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a
> message.'}]}]}

Heres what I've tried:

```
textRequests.append({
  "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
  "data": [
    {
      "range": "A1",
  "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
  "values": [["donkey"]]
    }
  ]
})
sheet.batch_update(textRequests)
```

I'm not exactly sure if I am writing the request properly. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that your request body cannot be used for `sheet.batch_update`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input values and an image of the output situation you expect?